# read formula from other sheet with phpexcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Trying to maintain some old dusty code, I am facing a problem with phpexcel in a import symfony command.

It seems that the library cannot calculate the formula correctly which is linked to another sheet of the same document as the active sheet.

The error I get is :

```
[PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception]
Price Template Map!B2 -> Invalid cell coordinate A
```

My code is :

```
try {
    $inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filePath);
    $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(array($this->getListName(), 'Template Info'));
    $objReader->setIncludeCharts(true);

    $objPHPExcel  = $objReader->load($filePath);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    throw new \Exception("Invalid file");
}
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

$fieldsNumber = array();
$filterData = array();
$templateIdList = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= $highestRow; $i++) {
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $i . ':' . $highestColumn . $i, null, true, false);
    $rowData = $rowData[0];
    var_dump($rowData);
}
```

The first line with the headers is read correctly, but the rest is not.

My formula is :

`=VLOOKUP(A18,'Template Info'!A:C,3,FALSE)"`

Do not hesitate to ask me more informations if you need it !

Thank you all in advance :) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the column reference: the PHPExcel Calculation Engine supports range references (even to other worksheets), but not row or column references

so

```
=VLOOKUP(A18,'Template Info'!A1:C100,3,FALSE)
```

would be valid, but

```
=VLOOKUP(A18,'Template Info'!A:C,3,FALSE)
```

can't be calculated

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getCalculatedValue()` function.

Comment: The problem is that rangeToArray third parameter is a boolean used to know if the library shall use ``getCalculatedValue()`` or not. It is currently set to true. If I set it to false, I will receive the formula in raw format.

Comment: And why not set to true?

Comment: It is set to true :)

Comment: This not work?
`$sheet->getCell('A18')->getCalculatedValue();`

Comment: It produces the following error : [PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception]
  Price Template Map!B18 -> Invalid cell coordinate A